# Including the pay.js script from Google Pay API gives an error

Tags: javascript, html, css

Including the pay.js script from Google Pay API (  ) gives this error : GET file://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans:500 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in the browser console, making the page load slower.

Comment: Can you give us a link to this script? It looks like it's trying to load the font locally (file://) instead of over the internet (https://).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial   ( Step 5 )

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by saving the script locally and deleting some stuff.
I deleted @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans:500)  (it appeared 4 times on lines 95,96,97,98 ) from the script and now it runs smoothly.